# UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ can’t decode byte 0x90 in position 4024984: invalid start byte

Tags: python, subprocess

I’m running a subprocess in full trace mode and displaying it using logger.info()

> ```
> > std = subprocess.run(subprocess_cmd, shell=True,
> > universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
> > stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
> > 
> > all_stdout = all_stdout + std.stdout + ‘\n’ all_stderr = all_stderr +
> > std.stderr + ‘\n’
> > 
> > logger.info(‘\nstdout:\n’ + all_stdout + ‘\nstderr:\n’ + all_stderr)
> ```

But I’m getting the below error when the subprocess is getting printed.

UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decide byte 0x90 in position 4024984:invalid start byte

I have tried giving universal_lines as False but it throws TypeError: must be str, not bytes.

I have also tried this -
std = subprocess.run(subprocess_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

> ```
> > stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=environ, encoding=‘utf-8’)
> ```

This gives me same UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Do you know what is the actual encoding used by the output of `subprocess_cmd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the encoding `encoding="unicode_escape"` instead of `encoding="utf-8"`

Comment: Thank you this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Partially unrelated, but for the exact same error, with my data only `byte_data.decode("latin-1")` worked